# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider==null

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

I have a problem with a class, log cat return this error when a run

```
12-05 23:19:18.299: E/AndroidRuntime(15460): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider==null
12-05 23:19:18.299: E/AndroidRuntime(15460):    at android.location.LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.java:1017)
12-05 23:19:18.299: E/AndroidRuntime(15460):    at com.rbrlnx.lugares.editarLugar.onCreate(editarLugar.java:110)
12-05 23:19:18.299: E/AndroidRuntime(15460):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-05 23:19:18.299: E/AndroidRuntime(15460):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
```

And the code is

```
     /************************************************************************************
     * 
     * Creamos un location manager, le establecemos unos criterios minimos para encontra
     * 
     ***********************************************************************************/
    LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criterio = new Criteria();
    criterio.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
    String mejorProvider = locManager.getBestProvider(criterio, true);

        //Obtenemos la última posición conocida
        final Location loc = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(mejorProvider);
        latitud = loc.getLatitude();
        longitud= loc.getLongitude();

        //Me centro en el mapa
          yo = new GeoPoint(
         (int)(latitud*1000000),
         (int)(longitud*1000000));
```

Only set the best provider and get the last know position but it crash, anyone knows why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because this line

```
   String mejorProvider = locManager.getBestProvider(criterio, true);
```

results in `mejorProvider` being null. What caused that null? Hard to tell. Either the provider you asked for does not exist or maybe you haven't enabled permissions in your manifest for requesting the user's location.